# Combine Categorical and Gradient Fill in Geospatial - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, r-sf

I'm trying to fill a combined categorical and continuous variable on a map. So, for instance, in my minimally reproducible example below, say I want to display the number of KrispyKreme Donut shops in each county, which is generally a continuous variable I want to fill on a gradient. But I also have counties that forbid KrispyKremes indicated by a "-1" and those that have them under construction "-2". I want to display these in a different color not mapped on the gradient. I also have NA in my real data.

--What I have so far:

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
nc$Status<-rep(c(-2,-1,runif(8)), 10)

ggplot(nc) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill=Status),color = "black") + 
  coord_sf(datum = NA) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

It breaks if I add the following line, obviously. So, I know I have the syntax wrong but it indicates what I want to do in as best as I can figure code for this

```
  scale_fill_manual(breaks= c("-2","-1", >=0),values = c("blue", "yellow", scale_fill_viridis()))
```

Any help is much appreciated, I've been on this all day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to cut your continuous variable into different categories.

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(122)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
nc$Status<-rep(c(-2,-1,runif(8)), 10)
```

First, check the distribution of your variable.

```
nc %>%
  filter(Status >= 0) %>%
  pull("Status") %>%
  summary()
#     Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
# 0.002789 0.153144 0.602395 0.491287 0.735787 0.906851
```

I decided to cut the variable based on the quantile as follows.

```
nc2 <- nc %>%
  mutate(Status2 = case_when(
    Status == -2 ~ "-2",
    Status == -1 ~ "-1",
    Status >= 0 & Status < 0.15 ~ "0 - 0.15",
    Status >= 0.15 & Status < 0.6 ~ "0.15 - 0.6",
    Status >= 0.6 & Status < 0.75 ~ "0.6 - 0.75",
    Status >= 0.75                ~ "0.75 - 0.91"
  ))
```

Now `Status2` is a categorical variable. We can plot it and use `scale_fill_manual` to provide colors. Notice that we need to provide the color code in the `values` argument. `viridis::viridis(4)` is to generate four colors based on the viridis.

```
ggplot(nc2) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill=Status2),color = "black") + 
  coord_sf(datum = NA) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "yellow", viridis::viridis(4)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly it, thank you. Have it technically, was just missing it conceptually

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks for this. The way `Status2` was constructed above makes it a character variable. I would like to plot a categorical variable instead. The code below generates a factor variable instead (`Status3`) and plots it in the map. It works.

```
library(sf) 
library(ggplot2) 
library(dplyr)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) 
nc$Status<-rep(c(-2,-1,runif(8)), 10)

nc3 <- nc %>%
  mutate(Status3 = factor(ifelse(Status>0,1,0)))

ggplot(nc3) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill=Status3),color = "black") + 
  coord_sf(datum = NA) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

However, when I try to do apply the same rationale (construct a factor variable based on a continuous variable and plot it a map) to my code I get an error.

> Error in if (type == "point") { : argument is of length zero

My code is below. The code works when plotting the continuous variable but not when plotting the factor variable. Does anyone know why?

```
# plotting continuous variable: WORKS FINE
ggplot(CS_mun_shp)+
  geom_sf(aes(geometry=geometry,
              fill=ppc_sih),
          color=NA) 

# constructing factor variable
CS_mun_shp2 <- CS_mun_shp %>%
  mutate(cs_above40=factor(ifelse(ppc_sih>=0.4,1,0), 
                           levels=c(0:1), 
                           labels=c('below 40%','above 40%')))

# plotting factor variable: GENERATES ERROR  
ggplot(CS_mun_shp2)+
  geom_sf(aes(geometry=geometry,
              fill=cs_above40),
          color=NA)
```

The only difference between my code and the reproduceable example above is that I need to specify `geometry` inside `aes()`, otherwise I get another error.

Comment: Is this an answer or another question or a comment on the previous answer? it might be worth having a look at StackOverflow guidance: [answer] and [ask]

Comment: Not quite reproducible, but I do have a few guesses worth trying.
1) you've obviously added levels and labels to your factor; is it possible ggplot plays badly with one or another. maybe try simplifying that step and populating those in ggplot directly.
2) The error seems to indicate ggplot is looking for 'point' data and not  line data. my guess would be this might be somehow defined as the wrong datatype in your sf frame.
Hope that helps...obviously can't diagnose directly without reproducibility.